# Optimizing mongodb query in python

Tags: python, mongodb, optimization, pymongo

I have a temperature sensor that generates data every 10 seconds. In an hour time span, 360 numbers are generated and inserted into the collection. I want the average value of these numbers for every hour time span of the day. So the expected result will be an array containing 24 average values.

Here's a document sample:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ef326b0192f38902dee27a6'),
'device_number': '867157044458446',  
'air_temperature': '+39', 
'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 10, 10, 56, 38000)}
```

In pymongo and Django, I am using a for loop to query the average value of each interval, which means 24 queries! It takes too long (+30 seconds) to get the results! There are probably better ways to achieve this, but I am very new to MongoDB! So how should I change the query to make it faster, other than indexing?

Here's the code:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 7, 00, 00, 38000)
end  =  datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 13, 7, 00, 00, 38000)

# break down the dates into 1 hour intervals
next_start = start
for x in range(1, 25):
    interval[str(x)] = {"start": next_start, "end": next_start + timedelta(hours=1)}
    next_start = next_start + timedelta(hours=1)

# get the avg value for each interval
avg_arr = []
for key, value in interval.items():
    avg = mongodb_query(database, collection, 
                        start_date=period['start'], end_date=period['end'])
    avg_arr.append(avg)


def mongodb_query(database, collection, start_date, end_date):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient[database]
    mycol = mydb[collection]
    
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "created_at": { "$gte": start_date, "$lte": end_date } }
        },
        {"$group" :
             {   "_id":"$device_number",
                 "value" : { "$avg":{ "$toInt":"$air_temperature", } } }
        }
    ]
    out = {}
    out['data'] = list(mycol.aggregate(pipeline))
    out['start'] = start_date
    out['end_date'] = end_date
    
    return out
```

Expected result:

```
# this is from 7am 2021/4/12 to 7am 2021/4/13
"avg_arr" : [
            { "data" : [ 
                            { "_id" : "867157044458446",
                                    "value" : 21.038922155688624 }
                    ],
                    "start" : "2021-04-12T07:00:00",
                    "end_date" : "2021-04-12T08:00:00"
            },
            {  "data" : [ 
                            { "_id" : "867157044458446",
                                    "value" : 22.61492537313433 }
                    ],
                    "start" : "2021-04-12T08:00:00",
                    "end_date" : "2021-04-12T09:00:00"
            },
            { "data" : [ 
                            { "_id" : "867157044458446",
                                    "value" : 26.6 }
                    ],
                    "start" : "2021-04-12T09:00:00",
                    "end_date" : "2021-04-12T10:00:00"
            },
            
            .
            .
            .
            
            { "data" : [ 
                            { "_id" : "867157044458446",
                                    "value" : 17.01197604790419 }
                    ],
                    "start" : "2021-04-13T06:00:00",
                    "end_date" : "2021-04-13T07:00:00"
            }
    ],
```

Comment: Why do you run 24 queries? Run just one. I am not familiar with Python, please provide 2-3 out of these 24 queries. Provide also expected result.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I want the avg value of a 1-hour span, and I need the avgs for each hour of a day (24 values). I don't know how to do it with one query if it's possible. I changed the question description and added the expected result.

Comment: Then have a look at my answer, I already provided.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$group` stage to something like this:

```
{"$group" : { 
      _id: "$device_number"
      y: {$year: "$created_at"}, 
      m: {$month: "$created_at"}, 
      d: {$dayOfMonth: "$created_at"}, 
      h: {$hour: "$created_at"}
   },
   "value" : { "$avg":{ "$toInt":"$air_temperature", } } }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain why and how this change would make the query faster? (I couldn't run the code, there were some errors) and why did you separated the y,m,d,h?

Comment: Because it provides all 24 results on **one** query - instead of 24. You ask for hourly average, thus grouping is done by year, month, day, hour.

Comment: thanks, you gave me the idea. but your answer is not quite right. we need to add "$project" and some other details to the solution to make it work. should I edit your answer, or post the solution myself?